# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'ajax')at request.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, html

necesito ayuda con mi código. Estoy creando una tabla de clientes con CRUD el cual ya puedo agregar, editar y ver los clientes, pero tengo un error al momento de eliminar.
Tengo una function en JavaScript llamada "fntDelInfo" el cual recibe el id del cliente que desea eliminar. La function en sí es una alerta indicandole al usuario si lo requiere eliminar, al momento de dar en sí efectivamente muestra la alerta de que el cliente fue eliminado con exito y se elimina de la base de datos, pero me genera un error al momento de generar reload a la table.
Esta es la función:

```
function fntDelInfo(idpersona) {

Swal.fire({
    title: "Eliminar Cliente",
    text: "¿Realmente deseas eliminar el Cliente?",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, Cancelar!"
})
    .then(resultado => {
        if (resultado.value) {
            let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); //validamos que navegador estamos usando
            let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Clientes/delCliente';
            let strData = "idUsuario=" + idpersona;
            request.open("POST", ajaxUrl, true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send(strData);
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    if (objData.status) {
                        Swal.fire("Eliminado", objData.msg, "success");
                        tableClientes.ajax.reload(); 
                        
                    } else {
                        Swal.fire("Atención!", objData.msg, "error");
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            

        } else {
            //Hicieron click en no
            
        }
        
    });
```

}

esta sería la tabla en html con el id "tableClientes":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tableClientes">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Identificacion</th>
                  <th>Nombres</th>
                  <th>Apellidos</th>
                  <th>Teléfono</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Y este es el error que recibo desde la consola del navegador al momento de aplicar "tableClientes.ajax.reload();":

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ajax')
at request.onreadystatechange
```

No me esta recargando la tabla para verla actualizada al momento de eliminar el cliente, debo de presionar F5 para que se recarguen los datos.

Intente agregarle: `location.reload();` y si funciona, me recarga toda la ventana pero no debería de ser así.

No agrego el código de mi controlador ni del modelo debido a que esta parte si esta funcionando correctamente, recibe el ID busca en la base de datos y elimina el cliente. Solo no consigo que se me recargue la tabla.